# How can I get the specific value after special characters

Tags: javascript

I have a value as `"SPAS1_4_2"` under which **SPAS** is fixed. I want to fetch the value `4` and `2` under different variable. these value can change based on a click however the **_** will remain same.

How can I get 4 and 2 value in seprate variable

Comment: First thing, the question does not show any search efforts to a _very_ simple problem. Second, there are many possible answers so **Too Broad**.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string using

```js
var str = 'SPAS1_4_2';

var pieces = str.split('_');

document.write('Pieces: ' + pieces + '</br>');
document.write('Pieces[1]: ' + pieces[1] + '</br>');
document.write('Pieces[2]: ' + pieces[2]);
```